# Is there a direct sum of linear maps like the tensor product of linear maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, direct-sum

Let $A_i:V_i \to W_i, i \in \{1,...,n\}$ be linear maps. Then the tensor product of the these maps is defined to be the linear map
$$
A_1 \otimes\cdots \otimes A_n: V_1 \otimes\cdots \otimes V_n \to W_1 \otimes\cdots \otimes W_n, \\
v_1 \otimes\cdots \otimes v_n \mapsto (A_1 v_1)\otimes\cdots \otimes (A_n v_n)
$$
Now my question is whether there is a direct sum counterpart to this definition, sth like
$$
A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_n: V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_n \to W_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_n, \\
v_1 + \cdots + v_n \mapsto A_1 v_1+ \cdots + A_n v_n
$$
and whether these definitions are somehow limited by the dimensionality of the space.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Yes. Not limited to finite-dimensional vector spaces. And if you pick ordered bases for all the vector spaces, tensor product corresponds to Kronecker product of matrices and direct sum corresponds to block diagonal matrices.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very nice.