# Finding a basis of $\mathbb{C}^4$ in which both $\sigma_1\otimes\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2\otimes\sigma_2$ are diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $(\sigma_i)_{i=0,...,3}$ be [the Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). I'm looking for a way to find a basis of $\mathbb{C}^4$ in which both $\sigma_1\otimes\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2\otimes\sigma_2$ are diagonal. I thought about finding eigenvectors for them, but this wouldn't be enough it seems. Any hint would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry i should have added a link to the wikipedia on Pauli matrices, and yes they do commute!

Comment: Thanks. Don't know what I was thinking about them not commuting :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T_1=\sigma_1\otimes\sigma_1$ and $T_2=\sigma_2\otimes\sigma_2$. As $\sigma_1\sigma_2=-\sigma_2\sigma_1$ we see that $T_1$ and $T_2$ commute. We can call upon the fact that commuting diagonalizable matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable, or we can just calculate.

Let us first consider $T_1$. The eigenvectors of $\sigma_1$ are $\binom 1{\pm1}$ belonging to eigenvalues $\lambda_{\pm}=\pm1$. Therefore the eigenspace $V_+$ of $T_1$ belonging to eigenvalue $+1$ is spanned by $v_1:=\binom 11\otimes \binom 11$ and
$v_2:=\binom 1{-1}\otimes \binom 1{-1}$.

Because $T_1$ and $T_2$ commute, the space $V^+$ must be stable under $T_2$. We see that
$\sigma_2\binom 11=\binom{-i}i=-i\binom1{-1}$. Therefore
$$
T_2v_1=\binom{-i}i\otimes \binom{-i}i=(-i)^2\binom 1{-1}\otimes \binom1{-1}=-v_2.
$$
Similarly $\sigma_2\binom1{-1}=\binom i i=i\binom 11$, and thus
$$
T_2v_2=\binom i i\otimes \binom i i = i^2\binom11\otimes\binom11=-v_1.
$$
It follows that

- $v_1+v_2$ is an eigenvector of $T_1$ belonging to $+1$ and an eigenvector of $T_2$ belonging to $-1$, and
- $v_1-v_2$ is an eigenvector of $T_1$ belonging to $+1$ and an eigenvector of $T_2$ belonging to $+1$.

Similarly, the span $V_-$ of $v_3:=\binom 11\otimes \binom 1{-1}$ and
$v_4:=\binom 1{-1}\otimes \binom 11$ is the 2-dimensional eigenspace of $T_1$
belonging to the eigenvalue $-1$. It, too, must be stable under $T_2$. A similar calculation (verify this, I did not doublecheck) shows that
$$
T_2v_3=v_4\quad\text{and}\quad T_2v_4=v_3.
$$
This implies that

- $v_3+v_4$ is an eigenvector of $T_1$ belonging to $-1$ and an eigenvector of $T_2$ belonging to $+1$, and
- $v_3-v_4$ is an eigenvector of $T_1$ belonging to $-1$ and an eigenvector of $T_2$ belonging to $-1$.

There you have it. The joint four eigenvectors are $v_1\pm v_2$ and $v_3\pm v_4$. They form a basis of $\Bbb{C}^2\otimes \Bbb{C}^2$. You can identify this space with $\Bbb{C}^4$ by your chosen way.

Comment: thank you so much! this definitely cleared up a lot of confusion on my part!

Comment: A question please!, could you explain what does the $\otimes$ mean in this context ? I'm a physics student but I'v never seen Pauli matrices with $\otimes$ before, Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: They seem like the tensor product of linear maps defined here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907678/is-there-a-direct-sum-of-linear-maps-like-the-tensor-product-of-linear-maps ?, Thanks again

Comment: @Physor Yes, I assumed that they are the tensor products of the corresponding linear transformations. When the linear transformations are replaced with their matrices (with respect to some basis), the tensor products can also be replaced with [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). I decided against doing that. My reason is that there are two natural ways to form a basis of $\Bbb{C}^2\otimes\Bbb{C}^2$ (the ordering!!), and I did not want to obfuscate the issue by making a choice. After all, here we are looking for yet another basis of joint eigenvectors.